# YQL finance gets null in results

Tags: yql

I'm just using one of the sample datatables in the YQL console. The YQL statement is `select * from yahoo.finance.stock where symbol="yhoo"`

Why am I get null in the results?

[Link to YQL console with the YQL statement](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.stock%20where%20symbol=%22yhoo%22&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.stock%20where%20symbol=%22yhoo%22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the yahoo.finance.stock YQL data table is no longer working. When run with Diagnostics enabled, several JavaScript errors appear. Because there is no official Yahoo Finance API, this community table is retrieving data by scraping web pages, and is therefore susceptible to page changes causing breakage like this.

The table yahoo.finance.stocks does seem to work, but I'm not sure if the data returned is what you're looking for.

Example query:

[`select * from yahoo.finance.stocks where symbol="yhoo"`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.stocks%20where%20symbol%3D%22yhoo%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck with yahoo.finance.stock (singular, no "s"). The data seems to be better maintained.